# My Batch file Is not looping?

Tags: batch-file

I am new to this and I am trying a basic example I saw on Youtube:

```
@echo off
echo this little program helps you to refresh a website 
pause
cls
echo but first we have to do some preferences
pause
cls
echo please enter the website name here
set /p website=
cls
echo please enter the time between refreshes
set /p time=
cls
echo Set limited or unlimited refresh
set /p refresh=
if'%refresh%'=='1' goto :once
if'%refresh%'=='0' goto :unlimited
cls

:once
cls
echo Preferences finished
pause
timeout /t %time% /nobreak
start %website%
exit

:unlimited
cls
echo Preferences finished
pause
:again
timeout /t %time% /nobreak
start %website%
goto :again
```

This code is supposed to ask a user for a website and a refresh time and it will refresh that website by reopening it in IE (Internet Explorer), however I have 2 problems with this:

1. The loop does not work if I enter 0 or '0' it will only execute once and exit the .bat
2. Is there a way to refresh a page without reopening the page in a new tab, for example just refresh the current tab ?

Comment: Hint: `exit` command

Comment: exit should work for :once so that it executes once, would it be better if I defined :unlimited first and then :once ?

Comment: No.. It's the same thing.

Comment: Ok I swapped definitions and :once is at the end now it loops indefinitely. Thanks! Do you have any idea though about the page refresh ?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax errors in your script.

---

## `EXIT` command

`EXIT` exits the script. You may want to change that to something else.

---

## `IF` Statement

```
if'%refresh%'=='1' goto :once
```

is slightly incorrect, as there is a missing space between `if` and the comparee. In addition, using double quotes ensure it to successfully compare with values including spaces.

```
if "%refresh%"=="1" goto :once
```

---

## Undefined Input

If variable `%refresh%` is not 1 or 0, it goes to `:once` and execute the code there.

---

## Refreshing Webpage

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.AppActivate("Chrome")
WshShell.SendKeys "{F5}"
```

Save this script as `Refresh.vbs` and put it in the same folder as the batch file.

Then, when you want to refresh the webpage, do `cscript //nologo Refresh.vbs`.

Comment: It's refreshing way too fast , it's not loading the page. The cmd box is stuttering and the page is perma loading.

Comment: Then, when you input `time`, input a bigger number

Comment: Ah yes I fixed it it was an error on my part. Sorry! Thank you very much.